# Prove that this dot product property does not hold

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm asked to disprove the following statement.

> For vectors $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in \mathbb{R}^3:$

> $(\vec{x}\cdot2\vec{y})+\vec{x}-\vec{y}=2(\vec{y}\cdot\vec{x})+\vec{x}-\vec{y}=(2\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})+\vec{x}-\vec{y}$.

I don't see anything wrong with this though. Why is any of this wrong? I can pull the $2$ out and dot product is commutive so I am not sure why this is wrong.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Looks correct to me!

Comment: Uh...the first (parenthesized) term is a scalar; the 2nd and 3rd terms are vectors. So adding them doesn't make sense.

Comment: But the question says that we are asked to disprove this

Comment: Well, this equation doesn't really makek sense, the result of the dot product is a scalar, and you're adding it to a vector. Are you sure it's written correctly?

Comment: I think I hear David G. Stork slapping his forehead. :)

Comment: Ahh thanks! I knew this was a really silly question.

Comment: Never outside maths I have seen people agree so quickly that the proof or disproof of an undefined statement does not matter. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one considers adding vectors and scalars to be an invalid operation -- in programming terms, it doesn't "typecheck".

However, there actually are contexts, where they can be combined in "formal expressions" as "multivectors", and the whole thing does make sense.  See the entire field of geometric algebra for example.

As applied to this particular statement, you can either take the first stance that "this isn't a valid expression", thus it is meaningless to ask whether it's true or false, or you can take the second stance, in which case it appears to be true, but only in a context where combining scalars and vectors this way is meaningful.